# How to Convert date, time & timezone to MySql Number (INT) format

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a plugin that allows adding dates from admin. I am trying to add some data into the database by running queries but I can't quite figure out how it's handling the dates. I know the plugin is saving the dates in (INT).

Example: This is the format used for generating the dates in wp-admin
12-01-2021 23:15 +0300

then end up in MySql database as (INT) value of `1610482500`

Basically, all I need is to find how I can convert dates in excel or PHP to convert the dates to integers. I tried Excel Date to Number Conversion but it generates about 5 digits only. Not sure how the date is converting so any clues will be very helpful

Thanks

Comment: I think that should also work if you remove seconds

Comment: Actually the timezone is ignored. If you remove the seconds, and do give a timezone, it results in an error... So, you are right the seconds can be remove, but then the timezone should also be left out.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way.

```
<?php

$datetimeStr = '2021-01-12 23:15 +0300';
$datetime = strtotime($datetimeStr);

//Displays 1610482500

echo $datetime;
?>
```